# onclick anchor tag, table row become visible using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, dom-events

I have made the same Google map web page with more than two destination to get direction between them. Now whenever I click on add more destination using anchor tag in web page, using JavaScript my table row should be visible in which one textbox for destination and label will be there. So can anybody tell whats the process of handling such situation using JavaScript?

You can check more about my problem by clicking on Google map get directions and adding more destinations. The same I want to do. Can anyone tell me about how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly this is what you need:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TableRowShow.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function()
      {
        document.getElementById('addDestination').setAttribute('onclick', 'addDest();');
      }

      var i = 1; // position of next tr to be shown

      function addDest()
      {
        var trs = document.getElementById('travelTable').getElementsByTagName('tr');

        if (trs[i] != null)
          trs[i++].style.display = "";
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <table id="travelTable">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none">
          <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" />
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="display: none">
          <td>
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="addDestination"
        ClientIDMode="Static"  NavigateUrl="javascript:;" >
        Add Destination
      </asp:HyperLink>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code should be pretty much self explanatory but ask if you have any question. :)

Comment: Exact what i want. Thanks buddy. :)

Comment: It never hurts to help! <battleship drops on him> :D